# .htaccess: Rewrite rule issue, how to redirect all to admin panel

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect my website to admin panel

Like

```
localhost/website/ => localhost/website/admin
localhost/website/login => localhost/website/admin
localhost/website/blog => localhost/website/admin
```

Here is my created rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/admin/$1 [L]
```

But this is not working

Comment: Where is your htaccess ? In root folder or in `website` folder ? Also, do you have other rules ? (Or other htaccess files in subdirectories ?)

Answer (score 3):

The following code will redirect everything to your admin page, keeping the attributes. This also applies to files who already exist !

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^website/admin
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   #OPTIONAL: Remove '#' if you want existing files to display normally
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   #OPTIONAL: Remove '#' if you want existing files to display normally
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/admin/ [L,QSA]
```

#### Explanation:

turn on the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

specific condition for rewriting: uri (the part after your domain name/localhost) cannot (! = inverse, NOT) start (^ = start of line) with `website/admin` = where you are rewriting to. This must be done to prevent looping.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^website/admin
```

Following 2 lines can be uncommented (remove the #) if you want that existing files are not rewritten

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The rewrite himself:

- ^ = start of line
- () = a substring
- .* = a number of arbitrary symbols, or no symbols
- $ = end of line
- /website/admin = the place to rewrite to
- [L,QSA] = extra options:
- L=last: stop executing further lines
- QSA=Query String Append: keep arguments, e.g. ?page=contact e.g.

  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/admin/ [L,QSA]`

I hope this clarifies my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^website/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /website/admin [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with some updated as per your code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php/component/quates   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php/component/quotes   [R=301,L]
```

Or Read this link:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d      
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(website/admin)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/admin [R=301,L]
```

**Explanation:**

First we make sure that the request is not for a file or directory that exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then we see if `website/admin` is exactly our requested URL (case-insensitive [NC]):

> `^` indicates beginning, and `$` end of expression.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(website/admin)$ [NC]
```

If all conditions are met we redirect to `website/admin` with HTTP status code 301 (last step [L]):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/admin [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^website/(?!admin).*$ website/admin [L]
RewriteRule ^website/admin[^/]+.*$ website/admin [L]
```