# How can I redirect from the bare domain to /index2.php in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to use .htaccess redirect `example.com` or `example.com/` to `example.com/index.php`.

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/index2.php [R=301,L]
```

But it is not working.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just `DirectoryIndex index2.php`?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114191/htaccess-rule-rewrite-rule-issue

Comment: (a) When you say *it is not working*, what do you mean? What is happening? (b) Please use proper example domain names, or your own actual domain names. (c) `example.com` and `example.com/` are exactly identical in every way. (d) Your example redirects to a different domain (the www. subdomain). Is that what you actually want?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index2.php index.php` is the only thing you need in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php/component/quates   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php/component/quotes   [R=301,L]
```

Or Read this link:

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the "/?" between the ^ and $. ModRewrite treats the base as an empty match so the search just needs to be "^$". Your rule would be for the same domain. If you want to add in the "www" part as well that's an entirely new question:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index2.php [R=301, L]
```